# How can i access my computer from my phone

Tags: python, kivy

I can't access my computer from my phone

MY CLİENT

```
import socket
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput


UDP_IP = ""
UDP_PORT = 80
MESSAGE = ""



anaDuzen = BoxLayout(orientation = "vertical") # Elemanların hepsini tutan ana pencere düzenimiz


ilkSatir = BoxLayout()
ikinciSatir = BoxLayout()

ip_txt=TextInput()
textdeneme=TextInput()
buton = Button(text = "Giriş Yap")


def onpresone(instance):
    MESSAGE=textdeneme.text
    UDP_IP=ip_txt.text
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
        sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE,'utf-8'), (UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))
    except: 
        pass
    textdeneme.text=''



buton.bind(on_press=onpresone)

class Program(App):
    def __del__(self): 
        pass
    def build(self):
        anaDuzen.add_widget(ip_txt)
        anaDuzen.add_widget(textdeneme)
        anaDuzen.add_widget(buton)

        return anaDuzen

#Program().run()
obj=Program()
obj.run()
```

------MY SERVER

```
import socket

UDP_IP = "192.168.42.16"
UDP_PORT = 80 #20,21

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, # Internet
                    socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDPcmd
sock.bind((UDP_IP, UDP_PORT))

while True:
   data, addr = sock.recvfrom(1024) # buffer size is 1024 bytes
   print ("received message:", data,addr)
```

**I can't access my computer from my phone**
so what sould i do? error in the my code or my phone i just can't understand that. i can take access with virtual systems on my pc but can't on my phone.

I would be glad if you help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

```
--permission INTERNET
```

to your .p4a file. 
By default no connects to the network are allowed.

Comment: i handle it. thank u so much. i handle with builozer.spec file permission.